# How to install a third party application

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there's a way to handle c# to install a third party application (mysql server 5.0 in this case). I'm not talking about a visual studio installer project but a winForm application that could be programatically used to handle third party installers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: short answer: yes... BUT: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working (error messages / exceptions...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used **[`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** for that. It can execute files on a given path, e.g. MySQL server installer. You would however need to supply the executable file.

Comment: Thanks, i don't have any code 'cause i didn't know where to start. I will start studying Process class to achieve what i asked. Thanks for all your answers –